# How to use variable in javascript escape_javascript rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I need to pass a variable js to rails, as a parameter, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
#function js
function load_custom_fields(){
  var id = $("MY_SELECT").val();
  $(".productHere").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'my_partial', :locals => { id:id} ) %>");

}
```

Comment: Will this work? `$(".productHere").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'my_partial', :locals => { id: " + id + "} ) %>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

```
"<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'my_partial', :locals => { id:id} ) %>"
```

To

```
"<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'my_partial', :locals => { id:"+id+"} ) %>"
```

Comment: this came as a string,
answer = + id +

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to add a placeholder inside the `escape_javascript` and then replace it with your JavaScript variable, for example:

```js
var id = $("MY_SELECT").val();
$(".productHere").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'my_partial', :locals => { id: '_ID_'} ) %>".replace("_ID_", id);
```