# How to use variable in javascript escape_javascript rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I found two other posts was the same subject in stackoverflow: [How to use variable in javascript escape_javascript rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794605/how-to-use-variable-in-javascript-escape-javascript-rails) and [How to use variable in javascript escape_javascript rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794605/how-to-use-variable-in-javascript-escape-javascript-rails/58684009#58684009)

I  applied the solutions exposed, and not only did not work, but something weird  happened. Well, at least I think it is weird that's a  Ruby variable  outputs one result when inspected and a totally different result when printed.

I am developing a rails 6  application where The contents of the Files are as follows:

something.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(url: "/graficos/partido", method: "get") do |f| %>
    <%= f.button "ClickMe",
           :class => "btn btn-secondary text-white mr-1 active",
           :value => "Clicked",
           :data  => {
                 disable_with: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>'.html_safe
            }
          %>
  <% end %>

  <article class="col-9">
    <div id="resultquery">
    </div>
  </article>
```

something.js.erb

```
var x=[1,2,3]
x=JSON.stringify(x)
var yt = 99

  $("#resultquery").html("<%= j (render :partial => ‘something’,
                                        :locals => {:xt => '_xt_',
                                                    :yt => " + yt + "
                                                    }
                                ).html_safe
                          %>".replace("_xt_", x ));
```

_something.html.erb

```
<p><%= xt.inspect    %></p>
<p><%= xt.class    %></p>
<p><%= xt   %></p>
<p><%= yt   %></p>
```

And now comes the weird part.   The output on the screen shows the following

```
"[1,2,3]"
String
_xt_
+ yt +
```

==================================================================

In this example, the approach " … :yt => " + yt + ", … “ Generates the  result "+ yt +" (the string itself instead of the value of yt) .  Jorawar Singh  suggested “=+ yt +-”, Even though I don't understand what  this means, it didn't  worked to.

The placeholder approach  (.replace("*xt*", x ))   generates the weird result:

```
<p><%= xt.inspect    %></p> gives "[1,2,3]", the value I expected to get
<p><%= xt   %></p>          gives _xt_ (xt[0] => “_”, xt[1] => “x”, ...), the string to be replaced in the  something.js.erb file.
```

My questions  are (q1) How can I pass a parameter since the other approaches didn't work. I did something wrong? (q2) What happened in the  placeholder approach? I tried it  without stringify and the first  result was "1,2,3", and the weird  second output  was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I was able to find out why the presented approaches do not work. The problem is a misconception about the client-server model.

When the server finds escape to Ruby (<%= ... %>), it replaces the contents with something. In other words:  the client do not receive  whatever is inside the Escape to Ruby. With this in mind it's easy to see that  the first approach ( <%= … :yt => " + yt + " … %>) is doomed:  the contents inside the  Escape to Ruby  will be replaced by the server and so will never  arrive  the client in this format. In this particular case  the server   will concatenate all the strings generating something like “... :yt => + yt + …” that will be sent to the client.

The second approach is feasible since the server generates  and sends  to the client a string containing something like “... :xt => '*xt*' … ”. The client into in  it's turn to work  replaces the *xt*  by whatever  it wants to be  the value of the parameter. The problem is that it behaves like Schrodinger’s cat: It's value becaames  both  '*xt*'  and "[1,2,3]". This must be some Ruby internals, and I have no clue why happens.

Anyway, since both methods do not work I engineered a solution  by using actions in a controller   that was created just to keep the  values of the parameters. In the JavaScript portion of the code, I send   an  Ajax request  to set the value of the parameters  in a controller#action class variables.    Inside The View   I get the controller#action  class variable values  with a Json request.

Ugly(?),  but works.